# Visibility binding with list item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, binding, listbox, visibility

```
List<MyItem> Reports = new List<MyItem>();

public class MyItem
    {
        public int CountAnswers{ get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeStartTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I am displaying it in `ListBox` using `Binding`:

```
<ListBox Name="QuestionList" ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >            
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountAnswers}"/>                      
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to display only items where CountAnswers are bigger than 0.
I have 100 items but only a few have `CountAnswers` > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then use LINQ ...

```
public IEnumerable<MyItem> ReportsWithAnwers
{
    get
    {
       return Reports.Where(x => x.CountAnswers > 0);
    }
}

<ListBox Name="QuestionList" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsWithAnwers}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >            
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountAnswers}"/>                      
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: And what if I want to display also DateTimeStartTime

Comment: Wrap your text block into stackpanel and add next one and bind it same as countsanswers property